# Nfc and Intent-filter

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter, ndef

I wrote a nfc text tag  like this

```
myscheme://company?page=2&poiId=140
```

Then i've created an Intent-filter like this in my manifest file in order to open my app (and then call a WS with informations from tag)

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" android:scheme="myscheme" android:host="company"/>
</intent-filter>
```

If i remove `scheme` and `host` params from data tag so everything works but by adding filtering it does not work anymore.

Why ?

Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [corvairjo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27598602/2425802) correctly wrote, "*you are mixing the record type MIME type (here text/plain) with the record type URI into one intent filter. You should use only one.*"

The point is that an NDEF record consists of a type information and a data payload (actually there's more than just those two fields, but those two should be enough to understand the concept behind it):

```
+------+---------+
| TYPE | PAYLOAD |
+------+---------+
```

If you create a text record containing your URI, you will get something like this:

```
+------------+-------------------------------------+
| text/plain | myscheme://company?page=2&poiId=140 |
+------------+-------------------------------------+
```

The receiving device will interpret the record according to its type field. Therefore, it will treat the payload ("myscheme://company?page=2&poiId=140") as a piece of human-readable text -- and *not* as a URI!

On Android, this means that the record is detected as a piece of human-readable information with the MIME media type "text/plain". Hence, you can only catch it with an intent filter like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

As the data payload is human-readable text, the intent filter cannot filter on any specific parts of that text (intent filters on Android can only match type information and URIs).

So if you want to have an intent filter that matches on the URI, you have to wrap the URI into a record type that specifically identifies the data payload as URI. This is typically done using the NFC Forum URI record type:

```
+---------------+-------------------------------------+
| urn:nfc:wkt:U | myscheme://company?page=2&poiId=140 |
+---------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Tag writer apps typically offer an option to write URIs/URLs onto tags. The Android NFC API provides the method `NdefRecord.createUri()` to create a URI record.

You can then use an intent filter like this to trigger upon a tag that contains the record:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="myscheme" android:host="company" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: In fact, with the last `intent-filter`, it does not work. When tag is detected, this is not my app which is running but a google app. I can see the following message ==> `ActivityManager : {act=android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED cmp=com.google.android.tag/com.android.apps.tag.TagViewer (has extras)}`

Comment: @aat Then you did not use a URI record to store your URI on the tag.

Comment: I think you're right but how can i specify uri record ? I use the following app to store tag (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tagstand.writer) but there is no information about uri record. Do you know another app or should i create mine ?

Comment: @aat Did you bother to read my answer? Have you tried the "Create Website tag" function of that app to write the URL?

Comment: Yes i've already read your answer and i've already knew that but i don"t understand my problem and yes i've tried "Create website tag"

Comment: @aat I'm not sure if that app is capable of writing arbitrary URI records. However, I know that (NXP's TagWriter app)[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter] is capable of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the record type MIME type (here text/plain) with the record type URI into one intent filter. You should use only one.

You can drop the MIME type definition and just go with the URI definition:

```
<data android:scheme="myscheme" android:host="company"/>
```

Comment: It does not work. If i add only your information i have no activity registered to handle NDEF and this is the default android app which is ran. 


`ActivityManager : {act=android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED cmp=com.google.android.tag/com.android.apps.tag.TagViewer (has extras)}`