# NFC type default app

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, intentfilter, ndef

I just started working with NFC. When scanning an NFC tag my app opens by default but I have 2 issues:

1. For some reason I can't see my app in launcher app browser.
2. How can I define to open the app only when NFC is URL type?

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

           <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
           <intent-filter>

               <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />

               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
           <meta-data
               android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
               android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
       </activity>
   </application>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem (app not shown in launcher) is due to the way multiple filter criteria are combined within one `<intent-filter>` section (see [Intents and Intent Filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html). You can easily overcome this by splitting your intent filters into separate `<intent-filter>` sections:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

The second problem depends on what data (NDEF records) you stored on the tag. If, for instance, you stored a URI record containing the URL https://stackoverflow.com/, you would use the following intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="stackoverflow.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

You might also want to check

- [Nfc and Intent-filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27591896/2425802)
- [Get NFC tag with NDEF Android Application Record (AAR)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25504418/2425802)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!

Comment: Can you give me an example what data (<data/>) to use if I want the app only open on specific text?

Comment: @Dim `<data />` allows filtering on data **types** only but not on specific data payload (e.g. text values). You would want to either use an NFC Forum external type (filtering on the type name), a URI record (filtering on a URL prefix), or a custom MIME type record.